# Flutter safety set constraints

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add a `ListView` to a `Column` in flutter, To fix the error

> The following assertion was thrown during performResize(): Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height. Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.

I have to add height constraint to the horizontal list. E.g. wrap in Container with height

How can I safety set `height`?

**My current approach is:** 1-set a small height 2- see yellow/black stripes of flutter 3- add `OVERFLOWED BY` value to step 1

But I see my approach works in some devices and not works in some other devices , If I set a larger height I have ugly white space , if I set small height I have cropped view, How can I set exact height?

In the following code I added `BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 108)` , If you set it 107 you have 1 pixel overflowed , the following code is ok in some devices , but in others the buttom cropped a bit from bottom

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Part A'),
          MyList(),
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          Text('Part B'),
          MyList(),
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          Text('Part C'),
          MyList(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 108),
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: List<Widget>.generate(50, (index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.amber[600],
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('test'),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code

Comment: I added codes too

Comment: Do you want all the MyLists to have the same height? Also, do you specifically not want it to scroll in the vertical direction (even if there isn't enough room)

Comment: It's just an example , I want to have a horizontal scroll , in real app each scroll has it's own contents and different height

Comment: Ok, and what if the total height of that content doesnt fit on the screen? Should it then scroll?

Comment: Yes , it wrapped in another vertical scroll, the view is like GooglePlay app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223699/discussion-between-pieter-van-loon-and-webmaster).